# Hibernate and Oracle10g: Tomcat times out

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, tomcat, timeout

I developed a web application on a test server, with an Oracle10g test database, using Hibernate 3.6.0 for ORM. Everything works fine on the test server.

When I moved this web application to the production server and the production Oracle10g database, I encountered a strange issue: the server times out when I try to run an update query in Hibernate (I receive an Internal Server Error).

These are the last lines logged by Tomcat:

```
2011-05-03 15:45:09,083 DEBUG (org.hibernate.pretty.Printer:113) - fsmodule.model.Organization{organizationid=65, ogroup=fsmodule.model.Ogroup#5, nature=fsmodule.model.Nature#2, name=Norway, factsheets=<uninitialized>}
2011-05-03 15:45:09,083 DEBUG (org.hibernate.pretty.Printer:110) - more......
2011-05-03 15:45:09,091 DEBUG (org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher:410) - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
2011-05-03 15:45:09,092 DEBUG (org.hibernate.SQL:111) - update RESPONSE set FACTSHEET_FACTSHEETID=?, QUESTION_QUESTIONID=?, TEXT=? where RESPONSEID=?
2011-05-03 15:45:09,099 DEBUG (org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher:66) - Executing batch size: 1
```

... and that's all! No error outputed, nothing else. The select queries work very well, but I have the same issue with the insert queries. 
Moreover, my users told me that the application worked fine at first, and then it stopped working correctly (I did not change the web application whatsoever in the meantime).

Also note that if I connect directly to the database with the same credentials than the ones used by the hibernate.cfg.xml file, I can flawlessly update the rows.

What could be going wrong?

Thank you all for your always-precious help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured c3p0 connection pool? http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool